# Compiling with clang++ on OSX but cannot include/find header files

Tags: c++, matlab, clang

I'm trying to install the spams toolbox on Matlab for optimizing sparse representation problems.

> The download page-> http://spams-devel.gforge.inria.fr/downloads.html

At very first place, when I tried to compile it with `compile.m` script, it said that :

```
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

And then, I found this post, I followed the instruction **below**, and it seems the previous error was **fixed**.

---

[image]

---

But now, I am getting error says that:

```
...mexArchetypalAnalysis.cpp:32:
./linalg/mexutils.h:15:10:
fatal error: 'typeinfo' file not found
#include <typeinfo>
```

When I went to the source file and comment this line, it gave me error on including **iostream**:
[image]

So I may think it is the problem about the libraries but I am not familiar with the C++ or C something, I need some helps.

Comment: Have you installed the command line development tools?  I've lost track of how it's done these days — it has changed various times, and may not still be necessary.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have installed by xocde select install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I fixed this by doing steps below:

**Install** gcc compiler and `openmp` support by `homebrew`:

```
brew install gcc --without-multilib
```

After installation, **In command line**:

```
alias gcc=gcc-6
alias clang=gcc-6
alias g++=g++-6
```

by doing so, you can use the cpp compiler with `openmp` support.

---

Let run a test program to check if `openmp` works correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int  print(int i){
    int tmp = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<100000000;i++){
        tmp += 1; // time consuming loop
    }

    printf("%d\t",i);
    return i;
}

int main(){

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
       print(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Compile:**

```
gcc -fopenmp test.cpp -o run
```

or

```
g++ -fopenmp test.cpp -o run
```

**Output:**

```
0   8   3   6   1   9   4   7   2   5
```

As you can see they are not printed in orders, this indicates `openmp` works correctly.